# Best way to hang a poster with human figurine oriented in opposite direction of text

Tags: text, photography

I recently bought and framed a poster that has a human figure standing upright, with text oriented against the human figure. The Japanese (I think?) is going downwards and the numbers are going left to right. The question is, what is the best way to hang this picture? Images enclosed[image]

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google image search shows the poster oriented just as in your image. Note also the word "as" (inserted into the Chinese at the left) is oriented the same as "2046".